# Array of timers with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to run multiple timers in a parallel manner using PyQt's QTimer objects. I'm trying to define an arbitrary number of timers (defined by n), and to launch them all at the same time : however, they'd all have different intervals (or timeouts), and these intervals would be different each time they'd start.

As of now, my test code looks like this :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import random

# Fixes an arbitrary number of timers and indicators
n = random.randint(5, 20)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        # Initializes empty lists of labels and timers
        self.indicators = []
        self.clocks = []
        
        # Loops the initialization of each label/timer duo
        for i in range(0, n):
            
            id = i
            
            # Creates a label to have a feedback on the timer's behaviour
            self.indicators.append(QtWidgets.QLabel("Time1 :"))
            self.indicators[id].id = id
            
            # Creates a basic layout
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
            lay.addWidget(self.indicators[i])
            
            # Creates the n°ID timer
            self.clocks.append(QtCore.QTimer())
            self.clocks[id].id = id
            
            # Sets it so singleshot mode,
            self.clocks[id].setSingleShot(True)
            # and links it to the event() slot
            self.clocks[id].timeout.connect(self.event(id))
            
            # Finally calls the event() to start the timer
            self.event(id)
        
        # Sets the main window's geometry,
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 400)
        # and pushes it upfront
        self.activateWindow()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def event(self, id):
        
        # Generates a random interval (or timeout) between 1ms and 10s
        timeoutConstant = random.randint(1, 10000)
        
        # Sets the new interval
        self.clocks[id].setInterval(timeoutConstant)
        
        # Refreshes the text in the associated label
        self.indicators[id].setText("Time " + str(id) +" : " + str(timeoutConstant))
        
        # Starts the freshly updated timer
        self.clocks[id].start()
        
        # Also prints a message to be able to track things
        print("Timer " + str(id) + " over")

# Creates the app and start the QT process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the output is that :
`argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'` for the `connect()` line ? I cannot wrap my head around why...

And `list indices must be integers or slices, not QChildEvent` for the `setInterval()` line ???

But how else could I manage a high number of these elements easily ? Thanks in advance for your help !

PS : Note that my code, when singularized, do run smoothly (tested with 1 and 2 timers and labels at the same time)...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [`event()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) is a fundamental function of all QObjects (hence, all Qt widgets), and it can *ONLY* be overridden with a *related* function (which gets a *Qt event* as argument, eventually handles it, and *always* returns a bool). You must ***NOT*** overwrite it for something else. So: 1. always choose appropriate names for objects, not generic ones ("event" is not a very good choice); 2. always check the docs to ensure that you're not overwriting an existing function: check the "List of all members, including inherited members" link in the docs of each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connected `event` slot incorrectly, `self.event(id)` is a function call, which leads to error since `self.event(id)` returns `None` so program tries to do `self.clocks[id].timeout.connect(None)`.

To bind value to a function you need to either use lambda with optional parameters or `functools.partial`:

```
self.clocks[id].timeout.connect(lambda id=id: self.event(id))
```

or

```py
self.clocks[id].timeout.connect(functools.partial(self.event, id))
```

You can simplify things greatly and avoid this problem altogether if you combine timer and label in one entity and encapsulate timeout handling inside it.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import random
import sys

class Indicator(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, id, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.setSingleShot(True)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        self._timer = timer
        self._id = id
    
    def start(self):
        self.onTimeout()

    def onTimeout(self):
        timeoutConstant = random.randint(1, 10000)
        self._timer.setInterval(timeoutConstant)
        self._timer.start()
        self.setText("Time " + str(self._id) +" : " + str(timeoutConstant))
        print("Timer " + str(self._id) + " over")
        
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        n = 5
        indicators = [Indicator(i) for i in range(n)]
        self._indicators = indicators
        for indicator in indicators:
            lay.addWidget(indicator)
            indicator.start()
        self.setLayout(lay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: There's an extremely important aspect that must be considered: [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) is a *fundamental* function of all QObjects, and it **MUST NOT** be overwritten with another function that does something that is completely different.

Comment: Oh you're right, I overlooked that ! Thanks for the reminder !